# How to store either record or class types in a collection and cast to TObject

Tags: delphi

I am writing a component inherited from TComboBox. The component has generic methods for adding and retrieving values, which could be record or class types, from a private dictionary with the key as the item index of the string representation of the value.

```
  TGenericCombo = class (TComboBox)
  private
    FValues: TDictionary<integer, TValue>;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure AddValue<T>(const StringValue: string; Value: T); overload;
    procedure AddValue<T>(Pair: TPair<T, string>); overload;

    procedure AddValues<T>(StringFunction: TCalculateStringFunction<T>; Values: TList<T>); overload;
    procedure AddValues<T>(Dictionary: TDictionary<T, string>); overload;

    function GetCurrentValue<T>: T;
    procedure SetCurrentValue<T>(Value: T);
  end;
```

This is the AddItem method, Values are currently stored as TValue, I have tried Variant also.

```
procedure TGenericCombo.AddValue<T>(const StringValue: string; Value: T);
begin
  Items.Add(StringValue);
  FValues.Add(Items.Count - 1, TValue.From(Value));
end;
```

The problem I am having is that when coming to set the selected value in the combo, I am casting the Values in the dictionary to TObject in order to compare with the Value past in. This is raising a 'Invalid type cast' exception at run time. TRttiHelper.ObjectsAreEqual takes 2 TObjects as arguments.

```
procedure TGenericCombo.SetCurrentValue<T>(Value: T);
var
  i: integer;
  FFound: Boolean;
  ListValue: TPair<integer, TValue>;
begin
  for ListValue in FValues do
    if TRttiHelper.ObjectsAreEqual(TValue.From(ListValue.Value).AsObject, TValue.From(Value).AsObject) then
    begin
      ItemIndex := ListValue.Key;
      FFound := True;
      Break
    end;

  if not FFound then
    ItemIndex := -1;
end;
```

I'm sure of what type the values, which again could be record types or classes, should be stored as in order to get this to work.

EDIT:
I thought it would be useful to add a couple of usage examples.

TTestEnum = (teEnum1, teEnum2, teEnum3);

```
  TTestObject = class
  private
    FStringProperty: string;
  public
    constructor Create(const StringProperty: string);

    property StringProperty: string read FStringProperty write FStringProperty;
  end;

  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    GenericCombo1: TGenericCombo;
    GenericCombo2: TGenericCombo;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TestList: TObjectList<TTestObject>;
begin
  TestList := TObjectList<TTestObject>.Create;
  try
     TestList.Add(TTestObject.Create('Object 1'));
     TestList.Add(TTestObject.Create('Object 2'));
     TestList.Add(TTestObject.Create('Object 3'));

     GenericCombo1.AddValues<TTestList>(function(x: TTestObject): string begin Result := x.StringProperty end, TestObject);
  finally
    TestList.Free;
  end;

end;

{ TTestObject }

constructor TTestObject.Create(const StringProperty: string);
begin
  FStringProperty := StringProperty;
end;

procedure TForm3.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TestList: TDictionary<TTestEnum, string>;
begin
  TestList := TDictionary<TTestEnum, string>.Create;
  try
     TestList.Add(teEnum1, 'Enum 1');
     TestList.Add(teEnum2, 'Enum 2');
     TestList.Add(teEnum3, 'Enum 3');

     GenericCombo1.AddValues<TTestEnum>(TestList);
  finally
    TestList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You say that you can only store records and classes, but that's not true. You can also put interfaces, anon methods, procedural types, enumerated types, strings, and probably others too. This looks like a pretty classic misuse of generics. You have objects whose types are not known at runtime (held in `TValue`) but then you use generic methods to work on them and generics require the type to be known at compile time. Rather than trying to answer the question you asked, I think it would be more fruitful to help you properly define a solution to your problem. Whatever that problem actually is.

Comment: Why do you declare the generic parameter on the level of the methods and not on the level of the whole class?

Comment: Thanks for the comment David. The problem I'm trying to solve is I want to be able to add items to a combo box from lists of objects (or records), set the current one selected and get the current one selected. I did try removing the type parameters but it doesn't work nicely with TValue as everything you pass in needs to be cast which looks really messy. If there is another type I can use to store the values I would be happy to do so.

Comment: @NineBerry Hi, I didn't think that was possible on VCL components. Do you know if it is?

Comment: Yes, you can use declare generic on whole class for VCL components (or any other class), but you cannot register generic component to be used in Form Designer. You would have to create such controls at run-time or register specific generic instantiation.

Comment: My guess is that the real problem is that you are trying to put the storage of your underlying data model into the UI control that displays the data.  If you separated the two then you wouldn't have this issue. I strongly suspect that if you solved your problem the correct way you wouldn't need to ask this question at all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The UI allows the user to make changes to the data which is the reason for this.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But you don't need to store the data in the control that displays the UI. In fact that's almost always a really bad idea.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't know of a better way of getting back what the user has selected. Otherwise, in the case of TComboBox, you are trying to relate back a string to an object.

Comment: You absolutely don't need to store the data in the UI control. There are many sound design patterns for this sort of problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, are you able to point me in the right direction of any?

Comment: Not really in the comments to a question. It's a broad topic, not very well suited to this format. Start by reading about model-view-controller, and take it from there.

Comment: "How to store either record or class types in a collection and cast to TObject" Short answer is you don't. You cannot typecast records to objects and this is the error you are having - invalid typecast.

Comment: While your whole approach is wrong, your core issue is that you need custom comparer based on type, you actually use and you don't need TValue nor casting to object. If MVC approach is too much, start with TGenericCombo<T> with custom comparer that will enable you to compare values, and use TDictionary<integer, T> also, using dictionary here is an overkill since you can just keep list of values you with indexes that match those in combobox items.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar thank you for the comments. I thought it would work as you can for example cast a string as an object. I am actually getting the error when trying to cast an object to an object which I don't really understand. We design our forms visually so I really need to be able to register it. I could as you say register one per required type but it isn't ideal. Really all I'm trying to do is bind a model to visual controls which I believe isn't far from an MVC approach, for example ASP.NET MVC involves binding the model (or view model) properties to HTML elements.

Comment: You cannot cast string as an object.

Comment: You aren't trying to bind a model to visual controls. You are trying to implement a model inside your visual controls. Utter folly in my view.